# How to search for bug in Service Fabric (on premise)

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

We are using SF on premise and one on month we have some bug on Service Fabric Explorer that we cannot find by checking our app logs. In those cases app is not throwing exceptions and there is something happening when SF loads our app. Can somebody tell me where to search SF exceptions that are shown in cluster explorer (web site). I tried to look into c:\SfDevCluster\Log but I cant find where are those exceptions exists in logs.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details about what bug do you see?

Comment: Most of the time it is "Partition is below target replica or instance count" - but the problem is not to solve this one but to know how to search in logs to find this kind of errors

Comment: That is a transient error that will disappear once the services have come online. It means the number of replicas needed for a quorum are not currently present.

Comment: I think you are not right - we found after some hours that accout on wich services are running were blocked but we have couple problems everytime diffrent. But we disscuss diffrent problem! I asked how/where to search for proper logs where I can see real error - in our case it should be problem with logging somewhere in logs but where those logs are?

Comment: @dnf The reason we are asking for more details is because this error can be caused by multiple reasons that aren't really errors: service initialization, cluster re-balancing and other stuff related to automated cluster management. If the issue is like that - then you won't find any errors in logs because there were no errors. The most detailed Service Fabric logs are located here: **C:\SfDevCluster\Log\Traces\fabric_traces-***. In general Service Fabric is log agnostic you can look [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/294#issuecomment-305504723) for more info.